# Create Mysql-Subtransactions in C# MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Tags: c#, mysql, transactions

I want to create subtransactions inside a transaction with the class `MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction`
As there is no method for like `CreateTransaction` or something else, I do not really know how to create a subtransaction in C# programmatically.

At this moment I think it could be something like this:

```
MySqlTransaction transaction = new MySqlConnection().BeginTransaction();
MySqlTransaction subtransaction = transaction.Connection.BeginTransaction();
```

Is this correct or is there something I am misunderstanding?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're intending to accomplish with this. Are you wanting parts of a transaction to commit/rollback indepedently, then commit or roll back the entire parent transaction? MySQL doesn't support "sub transactions", so there's no way to actually implement this on the database server even if you could design the C# API.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger I have some UI-Masks which must run in a transaction, in the mask there are possibilities to modify/create new data, each time a sub-window is opened there should be a new transaction, if the window is canceled without OK as return, the sub/-transaction should be rolled back. 

As MySQL does not support nested transactions, is there any other possibility to create these kind of behaviour?

Comment: Can you build up a list of the operations to apply in memory, then only send them to the database when OK is clicked? If Cancel is clicked, then just discard the in-memory changes.